# C# Changing WebBrowser.ScrollbarsEnabled property shows Invalid URI exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, browser, uri

When I simply execute the following line of code

```
wMessages.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
```

I can see the `System.UriFormatException` in IntelliTrace data, saying `"Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."`. I can't catch this exception, it's shown only in IntelliTrace. Removing the code makes my webbrowser work perfectly, but I need these scrollbars.

I can't understand what is the link between scrollbars and URI? Maybe it has something to do with the `Document` property of the browser? The URL of the document is `"about:blank"`.

Any suggestions?

UPD:

Here is the full code:

```
string h = "";
if (currentpage != null)
    h = template + "<body><div class=\"messages\">" + currentpage.Messages() + "</div><div></div></body></html>";
else
    h = template + "<body><div class=\"messages\">" + "</div><div></div></body></html>";

wMessages.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;

Misc.OpenNew(wMessages, h);
try
{
    if (wMessages == null) return;
    if (wMessages.Document == null) return;
}
catch (System.Exception)
{
    return;
}

HtmlElement body = wMessages.Document.Body;
wMessages.Dock = DockStyle.Top;                

const double MaxHeightRatio = 0.4;

int availableHeight = pContainer.Height - wHeader.Height - pFooter.Height;

int BodyHeigth = (int)body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

if (BodyHeigth > (int)(availableHeight * MaxHeightRatio))
{
    wMessages.Height = (int)(availableHeight * MaxHeightRatio);                    
    wMessages.ScrollBarsEnabled = true; // here goes the exception
}
else
{
    //wMessages.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    wMessages.Height = BodyHeigth;
}                
wMessages.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Can you show some more code, I have a feeling something else is going on here. Even though you said it works fine without the scrollbars, I'd still like to see a little more code. Thanks

Comment: I'm also getting an error when trying to set the ScrollBarsEnabled=false on the WebBrowser control. It's a COMException though. Very strange.